# How to write group by as in hql?

Tags: hibernate, group-by, hql

I wrote a hql like this:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(createAt, '%Y-%m-%d') as day, sum(amount) as orderAmount 
    from FoodOrder where deleted = 'false' and orderState = ?1
    and createAt between ?2 and ?3 group by day order by day
```

I got the error: Unknown column 'day' in 'group statement'.

And the hibernate log like this:

```
select
    date_format(foodorder0_.create_at,
    '%Y-%m-%d') as col_0_0_,
    sum(foodorder0_.amount) as col_1_0_
from
    food_order foodorder0_
where
    foodorder0_.deleted='false'
    and foodorder0_.order_state=?
    and (
        foodorder0_.create_at between ? and ?
    )
group by
    day
order by
    col_0_0_
```

Why the order by use col_0_0_ but group by use "day" and got error?

Any help thanks!

Comment: What Hibernate version are you using? Also, note that the generated SQL do not include the alias `day`. Please, try grouping by the same way you selected `group by DATE_FORMAT(createAt, '%Y-%m-%d')`.

Comment: It seems that the `day` word is reserved, so try to use another word as alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as Bonifacio's answer, it should be:

```
group by DATE_FORMAT(createAt, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Sorry for late comment this, and I can not set Bonifacio the best answer this time.